# CarrierWave - Seeding existing files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm working with the CarrierWave gem to manage pictures

I've already uploaded files with the gem. They are stored in the right place, with the right name.

Looking in the DB, the files names are stored in the :picture field

so I've pasted the value of the :picture field into the seed data

```
Artist.create!(
  name: "Bernard Herrmann",
  picture: "084af210edc917.jpg"
  ).tap do |artist|
  artist.albums.create!([
      {name: "Vertigo", year: "1958", cover: "535cdf6fcd1d97.jpg"},
      {name: "Psycho", year: "1975", cover: "b7cd34d7336d9d.jpg"},
      {name: "Taxi Driver", year: "1976", cover: "310bc65ef1a860.jpg"}
    ])
end
```

The db:seed works, records are created, but the fields :picture and :cover are empty

If I manualy put the right filenames into the database, my app will display my images

-> Is there a way to seed this filemanes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the database directly and skip out on CarrierWave:

```
artist[:picture] = 'picture.jpg'
artist.save
```